# How to tell Docker to store and run containers on an external drive

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am running Docker on Ubuntu Linux. I have a `Dockerfile` that brings in a lot of data from elsewhere. I put the `Dockerfile` on an external drive that I have mounted to the local filesystem (ext4). Then I ran the build from within that external drive filesystem.

```
docker build -t mycontainer .
```

I watched the drive usage as the container was building. All of the drive usage was on the root filesystem instead of the attached drive.

I have read some articles on changing the Docker root/base from `/var/lib/docker` to another location, but so far all I get is `docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`.

I also tried adding the `-g options` in the `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://  # original
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /new/path/docker -H fd://  # updated
```

This did not help either.

How can I tell Docker to use the external drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several things helped me get this working. First, I was mounting the external filesystem in a home directory, which may have been causing some permissions issues. So I remounted the filesystem under `/mnt` and updated permissions and ownership as follows:

```
# chown -R root:root /mnt/external-drive/docker-base
# chmod 701 /mnt/external-drive/docker-base
```

Then I created the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with these contents:

```
{
    "graph": "/mnt/external-drive/docker-base"
}
```

I restarted the docker service and all seems to be well. Doing a `docker build` and the external drive is receiving all the contents.

Comment: Note this flag is now --data-root https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#-g-and---graph-flags-on-dockerd